# What is the most efficient way to force immediate caching in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching, rdd

For timing purposes, I need to force a cache before executing a function.
My initial approach was to use the `count()` action as this will cache the RDD across all partitions, unlike `take()`, but is there a more efficient way to force it with regards to computation, communication or time?

```
// Load data, partition and mark to be cached
val data = sc.textFile("input.txt").map(_.toInt)
val partitioner = new RangePartitioner(16, data)
val partitioned_data = data.partitionBy(partitioner).cache()

// Force cache with count or something more efficient
partitioned_data.count()

// Do something
something(partitioned_data)
```

Comment: No need to force a cache, as cache will be triggered automatically when an action has been called, count in above case. Spark DAG will automatically create a plan to cache the data based on the transformation and actions.

Comment: If you truly want to force just trigger an action. I.e. Write it to a file.

Comment: @hagarwal I understand that cache is lazy thus only triggered when an action is called, my question is what is the cheapest action I can call which will trigger the cache, is there anything better than `count()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of this depends on what your are trying to do. If you notice that your environment is near its limit with persisted memory, I would advise the save to local, purge cache, reload, and re cache technique. However, below I have ncatalogued all the easy function and run them against a 2M record file to show their relative run-time in comparison.

The podium is as such:

1st (Three-way-tie) : Take(1), Take(1000), First; time: 9 seconds

4th : Count; time: 17 seconds

5th : Collect; time: 21 seconds

Disclaimer-1: yes I know count lost, but I declare it the secret winner because of a bunch of arbitrary style points it was awarded, mainly because I think this answer is slowly becoming 'Whose Line Is It Anyway'.

Disclaimer-2: All tests were able to run with default Spark memory configs except for collect, where I needed to set it to roughly a factor higher, and it gave the 21 seconds run time.

If you want to try it at home here is the code you can run (*plays corny gameshow music*):

```
val inputDF = spark.read.format("").load("")

var arrayOfCommand : Array[String] = Array("")
var arrayOfTime : Array[Long] = Array("0".toLong)

inputDF.count

val inputDF2 = inputDF.selectExpr("*", "'Count Run' as CommandColumn").persist

val countStartTime = System.nanoTime()
inputDF2.count

val countEndTime = System.nanoTime()
val countRunTime = (countEndTime-countStartTime)/1000000000

arrayOfCommand = Array("Count")
arrayOfTime = Array(countRunTime)

spark.catalog.clearCache
val inputDF3 = inputDF.selectExpr("*", "'Take 1 Run' as CommandColumn").persist

val takeStartTime = System.nanoTime()
inputDF3.take(1)

val takeEndTime = System.nanoTime()
val takeRunTime = (takeEndTime-takeStartTime)/1000000000

arrayOfCommand = arrayOfCommand ++ Array("Take(1)")
arrayOfTime = arrayOfTime ++ Array(takeRunTime)

spark.catalog.clearCache
val inputDF4 = inputDF.selectExpr("*", "'Take 1000 Run' as CommandColumn").persist

val takeStartTime2 = System.nanoTime()
inputDF4.take(1000)

val takeEndTime2 = System.nanoTime()
val takeRunTime2 = (takeEndTime2-takeStartTime2)/1000000000

arrayOfCommand = arrayOfCommand ++ Array("Take(1000)")
arrayOfTime = arrayOfTime ++ Array(takeRunTime)

spark.catalog.clearCache
val inputDF5 = inputDF.selectExpr("*", "'Collect Run' as CommandColumn").persist

val collectStartTime = System.nanoTime()
inputDF5.collect

val collectEndTime = System.nanoTime()
val collectRunTime = (collectEndTime-collectStartTime)/1000000000

arrayOfCommand = arrayOfCommand ++ Array("Collect")
arrayOfTime = arrayOfTime ++ Array(collectRunTime)


spark.catalog.clearCache
val inputDF6 = inputDF.selectExpr("*", "'First Run' as CommandColumn").persist

val firstStartTime = System.nanoTime()
inputDF6.first

val firstEndTime = System.nanoTime()
val firstRunTime = (firstEndTime-firstStartTime)/1000000000

arrayOfCommand = arrayOfCommand ++ Array("First")
arrayOfTime = arrayOfTime ++ Array(firstRunTime)
```

Comment: Thanks for making this comparison, I decided to stick with `count()` because `take()` would only cache the partitions it takes from instead of all partitions